# update field of queryset before passing to formset in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

i have a queryset that contains age of traveller.

```
qset = Travellers.objects.filter(traveller_type='1')
print(qset)
print(qset[0].traveller_age)
travellers_formset = TravellersFormset(queryset = qset)
```

this gives give:

```
<QuerySet [<Travellers: Travellers object (16887)>]>
33
```

i intend have a flag (is_renewal), which if true, should update the age of traveller by a year before passing to queryset to formset. so i'm doing something like this

```
if travel_quote.is_renewal:
    print('starting renewal section')
    for each in qset.iterator():
        print(each)
        print(each.traveller_age)
        each.traveller_age = each.traveller_age + 1
        print(each.traveller_age)
print('renewal section completed, checking for updated age')
print(qset[0].get_fields())
```

this gives

```
starting renewal section
<QuerySet [<Travellers: Travellers object (16887)>]>
33
34
renewal section completed, checking for updated age
33 <<<<< i want this to be 34 instead of 33 after the loop
```

Comment: You want the age to be incremented on every load of the page? Wouldn't you want it to be incremented after the formset is successfully saved?

Comment: the increment would be dependent on the flag. so on every page load, the age should be original age at start, then i need to check the flag and increment, only if the flag is set. then show the updated in formset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update in combination with `F` to increment a field

```
qset = Travellers.objects.filter(traveller_type='1')
qset.filter(is_renewal=True).update(age=F('age') + 1)
travellers_formset = TravellersFormset(queryset = qset)
```

Since `qset` was not evaluated by the update (the filter returned a new queryset) it will return the updated rows when evaluated

Comment: correct me if m wrong, I'm assuming that using F() will result in increment of age on every page load. however I want it to more like temporarily increase by 1 irrespective of number of page reloads